# Upgrade Sony VAIO laptop from Windows ME to Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

What is the recommended version of Ubuntu to use to upgrade from Windows ME on the Sony VAIO laptop?

Comment: Please add hardware stats - Processor speed and Type - amount of RAM, size of hard disk, graphics card etc. Windows ME is sort of old, but not ancient *(remember 98)* :-)

Comment: This asks us to judge what's fast enough for you; you haven't told us how much RAM you have, nor which model it is. There's  tremendous variation in Vaio models http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Vaio_505_series , from 233MHz to 2.2 GHz CPUs.  I would start with Lubuntu from http://lubuntu.net or Xubuntu from http://xubuntu.org as both are intended for low memory use. If they won't launch & run decently, then no Ubuntu version will work; you will need to use Puppy or another very-low-requirements distro. If Xubuntu works OK, you can try Ubuntu Gnome, Kubuntu or std Ubuntu w/ the Unity desktop.